# How to use Corrplot with correlation matrix created by hand (of type list)

Tags: r, list, plot

I used a for loop to create a correlation matrix, because I needed to use polychor to generate polychoric correaltions and I was only able to get polychor to correlate two variables at a time. Anyway, I created my own correlation table with the following code:

```
    for(i in 1:ncol(gd2)) {
        for (j in 1:ncol(gd2)) {
            corVal 
The table looks like this:


     head(dtnew)
       Better Afraid Alive Bored Drop Empty Energy Happy Help Home Hope Memory Satis Spirit Worth  TOT
    1:   1.00   0.32  0.29  0.39 0.36  0.46   0.25  0.43 0.39 0.13 0.46   0.39  0.50   0.45  0.48 0.67
    2:   0.32   1.00  0.25  0.20 0.24  0.30   0.23  0.30 0.43 0.15 0.44   0.28  0.31   0.29  0.34 0.62
    3:   0.29   0.25  1.00  0.26 0.28  0.46   0.38  0.60 0.35 0.19 0.41   0.10  0.49   0.53  0.43 0.65
    4:   0.39   0.20  0.26  1.00 0.36  0.56   0.31  0.36 0.39 0.16 0.32   0.23  0.39   0.35  0.44 0.67
    5:   0.36   0.24  0.28  0.36 1.00  0.44   0.41  0.37 0.43 0.31 0.35   0.22  0.42   0.37  0.40 0.72
    6:   0.46   0.30  0.46  0.56 0.44  1.00   0.32  0.55 0.51 0.18 0.45   0.17  0.62   0.52  0.64 0.75
    > 


But longer.
Here is the dput()
```

```
structure(list(Better = c(1, 0.32, 0.29, 0.39, 0.36, 0.46, 0.25, 
0.43, 0.39, 0.13, 0.46, 0.39, 0.5, 0.45, 0.48, 0.67), Afraid = c(0.32, 
1, 0.25, 0.2, 0.24, 0.3, 0.23, 0.3, 0.43, 0.15, 0.44, 0.28, 0.31, 
0.29, 0.34, 0.62), Alive = c(0.29, 0.25, 1, 0.26, 0.28, 0.46, 
0.38, 0.6, 0.35, 0.19, 0.41, 0.1, 0.49, 0.53, 0.43, 0.65), Bored = c(0.39, 
0.2, 0.26, 1, 0.36, 0.56, 0.31, 0.36, 0.39, 0.16, 0.32, 0.23, 
0.39, 0.35, 0.44, 0.67), Drop = c(0.36, 0.24, 0.28, 0.36, 1, 
0.44, 0.41, 0.37, 0.43, 0.31, 0.35, 0.22, 0.42, 0.37, 0.4, 0.72
), Empty = c(0.46, 0.3, 0.46, 0.56, 0.44, 1, 0.32, 0.55, 0.51, 
0.18, 0.45, 0.17, 0.62, 0.52, 0.64, 0.75), Energy = c(0.25, 0.23, 
0.38, 0.31, 0.41, 0.32, 1, 0.48, 0.37, 0.36, 0.31, 0.14, 0.4, 
0.43, 0.38, 0.74), Happy = c(0.43, 0.3, 0.6, 0.36, 0.37, 0.55, 
0.48, 1, 0.45, 0.21, 0.49, 0.22, 0.69, 0.84, 0.49, 0.8), Help = c(0.39, 
0.43, 0.35, 0.39, 0.43, 0.51, 0.37, 0.45, 1, 0.2, 0.51, 0.32, 
0.5, 0.44, 0.6, 0.73), Home = c(0.13, 0.15, 0.19, 0.16, 0.31, 
0.18, 0.36, 0.21, 0.2, 1, 0.23, 0.13, 0.13, 0.15, 0.26, 0.63), 
    Hope = c(0.46, 0.44, 0.41, 0.32, 0.35, 0.45, 0.31, 0.49, 
    0.51, 0.23, 1, 0.38, 0.48, 0.47, 0.59, 0.73), Memory = c(0.39, 
    0.28, 0.1, 0.23, 0.22, 0.17, 0.14, 0.22, 0.32, 0.13, 0.38, 
    1, 0.25, 0.24, 0.31, 0.66), Satis = c(0.5, 0.31, 0.49, 0.39, 
    0.42, 0.62, 0.4, 0.69, 0.5, 0.13, 0.48, 0.25, 1, 0.66, 0.6, 
    0.78), Spirit = c(0.45, 0.29, 0.53, 0.35, 0.37, 0.52, 0.43, 
    0.84, 0.44, 0.15, 0.47, 0.24, 0.66, 1, 0.51, 0.77), Worth = c(0.48, 
    0.34, 0.43, 0.44, 0.4, 0.64, 0.38, 0.49, 0.6, 0.26, 0.59, 
    0.31, 0.6, 0.51, 1, 0.77), TOT = c(0.67, 0.62, 0.65, 0.67, 
    0.72, 0.75, 0.74, 0.8, 0.73, 0.63, 0.73, 0.66, 0.78, 0.77, 
    0.77, 0.89)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001d7adc21ef0>)
```

</pre/>

I would like to generate a visual using corrplot. However, when I try, I get an error:
Error in is.finite(tmp) : default method not implemented for type 'list'

My data is indeed of type list. I have tried usuing 'unlist'. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Could you please `dput()` your data.

Comment: Sure. This is the first time I have used dput().

Comment: Try to convert it to a matrix `matrix(dtnew)` and pass the matrix to corrplot.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried converting to matrix with matrix(dtnew)but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your `dput()` output, possibly because you have a data.table. I can read it by deleting ", .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001d7adc21ef0>" from the last line so that it ends `class = c("data.table",  "data.frame"))`. Printing that out shows a problem with the last line/column (`Tot`). The bottom row in that column should be 1.00, but it is 0.89. We can trim that and use `as.matrix` (my mistake in the earlier comment) to convert the data frame:

```
gd3 <- gd2[-16, -16]
corrplot(as.matrix(gd3))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(corrplot)
M <- cor(df)
head(round(M,2))
corrplot(M, method="number")
```

[image]

Comment: Right, so I understand that 'cor' and 'corrplot' can work synchronously like this. However, I needed to use 'polychor' to generate a correlation matrix by hand. Are you aware of a way to get 'corrplot' to accept a correlation matrix populated by hand like it accepts the ones generated by 'cor'?